# How can I manually create links within a {pkgdown} site?

Tags: html, r, pkgdown

The pkgdown [autolinking vignette](https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/articles/linking.html) goes into some detail about how links are generated, both to other pages within the site itself, and to external documentation for other packages. I would like to know how to create such links myself. E.g, is there a function that can be run when building a site, something like `generate_pkgdown_link("my_function")` that will create such a link. This would be useful, e.g. for creating HTML flow-charts etc that describe the package structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to answer the same question, there is a documented solution which I somehow missed when writing this question - use `downlit::downlit_html_node()`, e.g.

```r
node <- xml2::read_xml("<p><code>base::t()</code></p>")
node
#> {xml_document}
#> <p>
#> [1] <code>base::t()</code>

# node is modified in place
downlit::downlit_html_node(node)
node
#> {xml_document}
#> <p>
#> [1] <code>\n  <a href="https://rdrr.io/r/base/t.html">base::t()</a>\n</code>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>